# Image View is not visible on SceneKit View

Tags: xcode, imageview, scenekit

My image is not visible in Scenekit, I also tested while button is visible, image button or button with image background becomes invisible. Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have finally showed an image over Scenekit View, but not using image view. I have checked out Fox2SceneKitWWDC2017 sample project and I see they used SpriteKit overlay. I used Fox2 sample codes to do so, as below. In case some body needs...

```
//
//  Overlay.swift
//  Remote
//
//  Created by Mustafa Akkuzu on 14.12.2021.
//
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class Overlay: SKScene {
    private var overlayNode: SKNode
    
// MARK: - Initialization
    init(size: CGSize, controller: ViewController) {
        overlayNode = SKNode()
        super.init(size: size)
        scaleMode = .resizeFill
        addChild(overlayNode)
        
        // Assign the SpriteKit overlay to the SceneKit view.
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func showImage() {
        // Congratulation title
        let congratulationsNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle.png")
        overlayNode.addChild(congratulationsNode)

        let w: CGFloat = size.width
        let h: CGFloat = size.height
        overlayNode.position = CGPoint(x: w/2, y: h/2)
        
        // Animate
        congratulationsNode.alpha = 0.0
        congratulationsNode.xScale = 0
        congratulationsNode.yScale = 0
        congratulationsNode.run( SKAction.group([SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.25),
                                 SKAction.sequence([SKAction.scale(to: 1.22, duration: 0.25),
                                SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.1)])]))

    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
    let overlay = Overlay(size: sceneView.bounds.size, controller: self)
    sceneView.overlaySKScene = overlay
    overlay.showImage()
```